# how to create room database with user movies and favourites?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm planning to create a room database to simulate a rest-api, so what I'd like to do is to have inside the database data stored acting as a rest-api. My idea is to have a table called movies (id, name, etc..) and then an user can save this movie as a favourite, so, I was thinking to have an User table (always is going to be the same since it's a fake) and then I was thinking to add inside the users table, a list of movies called favourites.

Is there any other optime way?

My idea is:

### User

id name age favouriteList : List

### Movie

id name genre duration

The goal is to :

Ask for the list of movies and know the favourites of the current user but always return the same list, just when presenting I'd have to be able to check which one is favourite and which one not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is a way to pre-populate Room with data. All you have to do is call a function in your configuration:

If you put your db file in your `assets` folder:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase.class, "Sample.db")  
    .createFromAsset("database/myapp.db")
    .build()
```

However, there are some details that might help you, so just go through [this](https://coroutinedispatcher.com/posts/prepopulate-room-with-data/) article once.

You can also go through [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate)

EDIT: For your other question: How to organise tables. Your flow is correct. Have a user table first:

```
@Entity(tableName = "user)
data class User(
  @PrimaryKey
  @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
  val id: Int,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "favorite_movies")
  val favoriteMovies: List<Movie>,
  ... other fields here
)
```

And then on the `Movie` entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "movies",
foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = User::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("user_id"),
        onDelete = CASCADE
    )]
)
data class Movie(
  @PrimaryKey
  @ColumnInfo("id")
  val id: Int,

  @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id", index = true)
  val userId: Int,

  .... other fields here
)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, about the organization of the data? I mean, I want to have an user (now is always the same) and then I have a list of movies pre-defined and then the user can mark a movie as his favourite, how would you create these entities?

Comment: Because for me is confusing the way I'd ask for the list of movies and then get from there the favourites to me, I'd say that I have to search and filter by user_id

Comment: I see, but with this structure can I ask for all the movies and get the favourites for the exact user that is asking for? For example if I have the List of movies isn't better to have inside of movies a list of user_id and an attribute named favourite (first would be false) ? I mean I want to understand how I'm supposed to get all the movies but with a flag or something for the user logged in to know that this movie is favourite or not

Comment: Because what I mean is, not to have a screen to show my favourites, but get all the list and the user know which one is his favourite or not.

Comment: You can just ask if you can find the movie in user favourite movies. it's simpler.
`if(userMovies.contains(movie))`

Comment: But my question is more about, perhaps is better to have the favourite in the movies table than user. at least to show the favourites

Comment: I would do it like this

Comment: Can you provide an example how could I do the dao for instance to get all the movies and get all the list of movies and how do I know if this movie is favourite of the user?

Comment: You either select all from movies and select all from users and try to map, (just ask in the adapter, if the user contains this movie, make the star yellow or something). or you use joins

Comment: But just with a query could I get all the movies? and then use a mapper or something to create like a data class which contains a Movie with a flag favourite? And put either true or false depends of it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220012/discussion-between-stuartdto-and-coroutinedispatcher).